# Citing in footnotes but have trouble with Figures

Tags: captions, footcite

I am citing with footnotes (because I have to) and when I include `\footcite` within `\caption`, I only see the footnotes in List of Figures and not on the page where I put the figure. Because I am doing this with footnotes, I have a certain enumeration, so it must be on the same page. Any solution for this? I used `\protect` but didn't really work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: No solution? :(

Comment: you have to give a minimal working example (MWE) including preamble, and `\begin/end{document}`. Thus people can help you find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown any code so how do you think that we might know what you have done?

My guess is that you have put `\footcite` in the required `\caption` argument. This is automatically put in the LoF. Use the optional argument:

```
\caption[title for LoF (without footcite)]{title + footcite in main document}
```